# Remote deploy of [akka://Test/user/simpleActor] is not allowed, falling back to local

Tags: java, linux, scala, server, akka

I have two servers:

Server1: 10.7.44.49
Server2: 10.7.44.71

and two actorSystems running on those servers:

```
akka://Test@10.7.44.49:5555
akka://Test@10.7.44.71:5555
```

I'm trying to deploy an actor from Server2 to Server1 remotely.

To achieve that, I set in the configuration of Server2:

```
deployment {
/simpleActor {
remote = "akka://Test@10.7.44.49:5555"
}
```

But I get:

```
[WARN] [09/07/2022 13:36:53.156] [sbt-bg-threads-1] [akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider] Remote deploy of [akka://Test/user/simpleActor] is not allowed, falling back to local.
```

I also tried to achieve it programmatically:

```
val address = AddressFromURIString("akka://Test@10.7.44.49:5555")
val actorRef = system.actorOf(Props[SimpleActor]().withDeploy(Deploy(scope = RemoteScope(address))))
```

But the result is the same.

Any clue on deploying an actor to another actorSystem running on a different machine?

Reference: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting.html#programmatic-remote-deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is logged in the `else` clause of [this `if`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/044bb2dc0a3804d7fe33a1d3e988830256c108fa/akka-remote/src/main/scala/akka/remote/RemoteActorRefProvider.scala#L437):

```scala
hasClusterOrUseUnsafe && shouldCreateRemoteActorRef(system, address)
```

- `hasClusterOrUseUnsafe` returns true if and only if one of `akka.actor.provider = cluster` or `akka.remote.use-unsafe-remote-features-outside-cluster = true` in your config
- `shouldCreateRemoteActorRef` is almost certainly going to be true (unless you're using a custom `RemoteActorRefProvider`, in which case you're basically on your own)

So setting one of

```
akka.actor.provider = cluster
akka.remote.use-unsafe-remote-features-outside-cluster = true
```